# Angular navigate to route from service

Tags: angular

I have a service that does some api calls and I need it to go to a different component is something goes wrong.

So I have this:

```
if (error.status === 0) {
      window.alert('Error status is 0');
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
}
```

The alert is actually showing so I know something has gone wrong.

Next I've added:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/error');
this.router.navigate(['error']);
```

None of the above is routing to the error component.

Does `'navigateByUrl'` or `'navigate'` not work in services?

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you also share your router module.

Comment: It's basically this: const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent },
];

Comment: Works from any component but not from the service

Comment: what is the error it is showing in browser console ?

Comment: Yeah I'm getting: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigateByUrl' of undefined

Comment: Based on error, it seems like your router instance does not get initialized. check that once or post whole service file in question so that it will be easier look into issue.

Comment: maybe you didn't inject router module in your service, it should be in the constructor of your service, something like:  constructor( private router: Router  ) {}

Comment: It's there ...constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private router: Router) {}

Comment: why are u using `navigateByUrl` and `navigate` ?

Comment: one didn't work so I added both

Comment: Without further information I think it is hard to help you out. `this.router.navigate(['error'])` should work. If you get a `TypeError` there is something else wrong.